How can I customize the 'Check In' box that appears when a document is checked in to a SharePoint Doc Library?
We have a SharePoint 365 Library that has approvals, versioning and check in enabled. We have Power Automate flows handling the approval, but we would like to customize the box that appears when checking a document in. We need to have the user validate some questions before the document can be checked in. The plan is to use radio buttons or check boxes.
I have tried with Power Apps, but that only allows me to create a from for users to edit the meta data. I did think that maybe I could use that form and have the flow only trigger based on the responses there, but that isn't working well and is cumbersome for end users. Any help here at all will be greatly appreciated!
